# Smart way to ensure Spring context stays alive during ThreadPoolTaskExecutor testing

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, junit, threadpool

We're trying to implement a sort of ensurance between multi-threaded part of our application and the database access so that DB would not be hit with too many threads (customer requirement) and at the same time keep other parts of the system fully utilized with necessary amount of threads.

Design seems to work of (spring batch partitioning + handling data access with a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) but the issues is with testing the design (based on http://helenaedelson.com/?p=432).

For now I've had to add Thread.sleep(4000) into to my unit test to make sure that Spring context is not killed off from under the test before the spawned extra threads have a change to finish their work and give return values back to the main thread.

Would anyone have some better ideas on how to make this test implementastion smarter?

tester:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:partitionJdbcJob.xml" })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class TaskTests {
protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TaskTests.class);

@Autowired
private OrderServiceImpl orderService;

@Test
public void testExecution() {
    logger.info("Starting execution thread...");

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        orderService.dispatch();
    }

    try {
        // So that spring context is not destroyed from under the multi-threaded runnables
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

test service:

```
@Service("orderServiceImpl")
public class OrderServiceImpl {
protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderServiceImpl.class);

@Resource(name = "beanTaskExecutor")
private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
// private AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

CompletionService completionService;

@Autowired
public void OrderServiceImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
    completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService(taskExecutor);
}

public void dispatch(final RetailPriceOptimization order) {
    logger.info("Starting dispatch execution...");

    if (this.taskExecutor != null) {
        logger.info("taskExecutor found...");
        this.taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                withExecutor(order);
            }
        });
    }

    try {
        Object future1 = completionService.take().get();
        Object future2 = completionService.take().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.info("Completed dispatch execution...");
}

private void withExecutor(final RetailPriceOptimization order) {
    logger.info("Starting withExecutor execution...");

    Object result1 = completionService.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() {
            return findById("0000dd2gsl1u1546");
        }
    });
    Object result2 = completionService.submit(new Callable() {
        public Object call() {
            return orderDao.find(new Long("16"));
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Right now your test seems to be synchronous since you are calling the `completionService .take()` twice inside of the `dispatch(...)` method.  The `take()` will wait until the job finishes.  So as I read it, you don't need your thread sleep at all.

Also, I don't see the need for the `CompletionService` at all.  You should just keep the 2 futures and then call `get(...)` on them one at a time.  Seems like you are waiting for the 2 calls to finish anyway and they will be run at the same time.  `CompletionService` are only good when you can start work on one of the results immediately.

Answer (score 0):

What you dont try to refactor your service a little bit as.

```
@Service
public class ConcurrentService{

    public Map<String, Object> createList(){
       this.asynCall();
    }

    @Async("taskExecutor")
    private Future<Map<String, Object>> asynCall(){
            //I will use submit instead of execute
            return this.taskExecutor.submit(new Callable(){
                 //Override the proper logic following interface
             })
    .....
    }

}
```

For all the process you want to execute in parallel use a new method follow with the @Async , this make it execute it async, in the method that you use to merge responses or just the one to use to start parallel process, use the Future API to wait until job isDone.

> boolean [isDone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()) Returns true if this task completed. Completion may
>   be due to normal termination, an exception, or cancellation -- in all
>   of these cases, this method will return true.

This will make wait for all the futures to be completed

```
while(future1.isDone() future2.isDone()){
//Do Something in the meanwhile
}
//Code will start the execution once both process are completed
```

You can build a wrap method to make easier and more dynamically wait for completition.

Spring config to do that is:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor"  mode="aspectj" />

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="50" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="300" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="30" />
</bean>
```

Also to me this is integration testing as your using real objects and services, the config above will result in the test executes correctly with all the business logic, and will wait until all the processes are complete, so you wont need to have a Thread.sleep, after the method execution in your example>

```
orderService.dispatch();
```

You will be able to create the list of Asserts to verify the process is working as expected, dont forget this as a part of the testing purpose.